# Media queries mobile menu and normal menu

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

My website has 4 media queries, one for mobile (fluid), one for tablet (720px), small screens (940px) and big screens (1140px). Mobile and tablet will show a mobile menu, small and big screen will have a normal menu which will show the sub-menu on hover.

**The Queries:**

```
< 768px // Mobile 
> 768px and < 1024px // Tablet
> 1024px and < 1200px // Small screens
> 1200px // Big screens
```

**The Viewport:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

**The problem**

iPad will show Small screens (hover menu) because the width is 1024px. Tablet and mobiles (or touch devices) should only show the mobile menu regardless of there width, because touch devices can not handle `:hover`.

**Solutions:**

Neither one of the underlying solutions are the way I want it. I am looking for a pure CSS version to detect either a mobile devices or a touch device. Off course one of these solutions will be applied if there is no CSS option.

*Modernizr* - It can detected if a device is mobile or tablet and it can detect if it is a touch device. Downside is that you have to add a package which will result in an extra http request and it will make the website 'slower'. An other downside is that it will not work when Javascript is disabled.

*Javascript* - Use Javascript to detect all `userAgent` for mobile and tablets. Downside is that it will not work if Javascript is disabled and you have to keep an eye out for new devices / `userAgent`

*CSS (device-max-width)* - Well this seems to be the solution, but I am afraid of conflicts when I have a `(device-max-width: 768px)`, `(device-min-width: 768px)` together with my normal desktop queries `(min-width:1024px) and (max-width: 1200px)` and `(min-width: 1200px)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution for your problem exists in the CSS specifications, but has not been implemented yet:
https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#hover

```
@media (hover) {
  /*styles for devices where the user can hover*/
}
@media not (hover) {
  /*styles for devices where the user cannot hover, such as mobiles and tablets*/
}
```

Until browsers get around implementing it, you're stuck with nasty workarounds such as browser sniffing.

Comment: So this means that there is no CSS option for this? Even not with different media queries / sizes?

Comment: Some small computers have smaller screens than some large tablets, so screen size won't cut it. You can try to use exact screen sizes rather than ranges to try and detect particular devices, but you'll get lots of false positives and false negatives. The clean CSS solution is what I said, but I may be a few years off. Anything else, as far as I know, will be somewhat hacky and brittle, or doing some form of UA sniffing, or both.

Comment: Oké, well let's hope they will add it soon. Until than I will try to use a JS script which will detect it. Thanks for the help! :)